# Is it possible to have a TypeScript Common project, used by 2 TypeScript Angular projects?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

As the title suggests, I'd like to have a common TypeScript code, mainly for server communication, that is somehow referenced by 2 Angular projects.

I'm thinking of making a common TypeScript project that is packaged and then consumed by the two, but I don't know how to do that (or if it's the best solution).

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mainly for server communication, that is somehow referenced by 2 Angular projects.

Best that you publish it as a seperate npm module. You can use use projects seemlessly from other typescript projects https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/node/nodejs.html